# WHERE CASE WHEN BETWEEN Two Months - ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I've piggybacked this query (which works) from a different subquery, but I've added a CASE clause in the WHERE. It's throwing me a 'missing keyword' error and I can't see what the issue could be. Unfortunately I have no one around who can help me look for what I'm guessing is a very small error I'm not seeing.

The CASE essentially should be saying:

```
WHEN MONTH BETWEEN JAN AND JUN THEN START_DATE > 30/06/[CURRENT YEAR]
ELSE START_DATE > 30/06/[CURRENT YEAR] + 1
```

```
SELECT fp.object_id inv_id
      ,nvl(round(SUM((oc.finish_date - oc.start_date) * oc.slice)),0) forecast_amt
FROM odf_ssl_cst_dtl_cost oc
left join fin_cost_plan_details fd on fd.id  = oc.prj_object_id
left join fin_plans fp on fp.id = fd.plan_id
    and fp.plan_type_code = 'FORECAST'
    and fp.is_plan_of_record = 1 
WHERE CASE
    WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
        THEN oc.start_date > DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY,0,GETDATE()),0)))
    ELSE oc.start_date > DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))
END
GROUP BY fp.object_id
```

Comment: A good start at debugging this would be to write a simpler version of this query that uses actual hardcoded date values.  Once the clutter from the variables is gone, maybe the error will be more apparent.

Comment: Unfortunately I deal a lot with returning values from shifting financial years based on the value I'm returning and the current date, which is why this gets quite annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle? Oracle does not support the functions `GETDATE` or `DATEADD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` returns a value, but you can't use it to return a boolean to a `WHERE` condition.

Rewrite the `WHERE` clause to move the comparison *outside* the `CASE` and have the `CASE` just return the value to be compared:

```
WHERE oc.start_date >
    CASE
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
            THEN DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY,0,GETDATE()),0)))
        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YYYY, DATEDIFF(YYYY,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))
    END
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That definitely did partially fix it. I realise I've confused myself a bit as well. GETDATE() is SQL Server, not Oracle. I think DATEADD() is also not Oracle, so I have to look in to that bit now as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support the functions `GETDATE`, `DATEDIFF` or `DATEADD`, you would want to use `SYSDATE`, `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and `ADD_MONTHS`.

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value; it cannot return an expression.

Your logic can be simplified to add 6 months to the current date and then `TRUNC`ate that date to the start of the year and add another 6 months and compare that value to `start_date` (which removes the need for any branching logic):

```sql
SELECT fp.object_id inv_id,
       COALESCE(round(SUM((oc.finish_date - oc.start_date) * oc.slice)),0)
         AS forecast_amt
FROM   odf_ssl_cst_dtl_cost oc
       LEFT JOIN fin_cost_plan_details fd
       ON     fd.id  = oc.prj_object_id
       LEFT JOIN fin_plans fp
       ON     fp.id = fd.plan_id
          AND fp.plan_type_code = 'FORECAST'
          AND fp.is_plan_of_record = 1 
WHERE  oc.start_date > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 6), 'YY'), 6)
GROUP BY fp.object_id
```

If you are not using Oracle or have implemented user-defined functions for `GETDATE` and `DATEADD` then:

```sql
WHERE  oc.start_date > DATEADD(MONTH, 6, TRUNC(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, GETDATE()), 'YY'), 6)
```